# How to load Images from NSMutableArray in UITableviewCell in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I need to laod a image from `NSMutableArray` which is loaded from service url.I can retrieve the image tag from XML response.Now I want that image in a `UITableViewCell`

My array looks like this :

```
(
{
Image="46b6daca-3.png";
}
{
Image="9251bfe5-d.jpg";
}
)
```

How can I load each image in a seperate `UITableViewCell` ?

For creating a UILabel I knew it is like this :

```
 NSMutableDictionary *d = (NSMutableDictionary *) [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 UILabel *line1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 68, 320,10)];
    line1 .font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"arial" size:12];        
    [line1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
    [line1  setText:[d valueForKey:@"Name"]];
    line1.tag=113;
    [cell addSubview:line1 ];
    [line1  release];
```

How can I do it for UIImage?

Comment: Yes it is in the array as i have given the array response above

Comment: you need to pass the image url in the xml responce instead of passing image name.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[ d objectForKey:@"Image"]];
[cell.contentView addSubView:img];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for setting the image:

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageNamed:[d objectForKey:@"Image"];
cell.imageView.image = img;
```

Here d is your `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: But I got error "Program received Signal SIGABRT"..What could be the possible reason.?

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: are you storing the image in NSDictionary or in NSMutableArray

Comment: No I have got image in NSMUtableArray .From that I m taking it in NSDictionary to display in tableViewCells

Comment: No there are some other fields also.I have retreived them in UILabels .Now I want to retrieve images along with those

Comment: Yes I have tried still getting error "Program received signal SIGABRT" at this line cell.imageView.image = img; .I can see the warning like this :Incompatible pointer types assigning to UIImage from UIImageView. at that line.What should I do?

Comment: Now I couldnot see the image added to the cell (displayed on the screen) .But what I can see is space is allocated for image..y so ?

Comment: @arizah: If you need to bind images to imageview you need that image on bundle. Or binding it from the `photolibrary` you need `asset url` Or if you need to bind image from web you need `weburl`

Comment: May be I should set fixed dimensions to all the images and then add ?If so how can I do it ?

Comment: No I dont have all of them.I m binding images and all the data all got in array  from wcf service url ..Should I use weburl and how ?

Comment: In your array I saw only image name, where is `imageData` ?

Comment: I got that image name from service url as XML response and so i did XML parsing I retrieved the Image name..my url is like :http://something/services/User.svc/GetXml in this one of the tag is like <Image>46b6daca-3.png</Image>.So I retrieve it from there by doing XML parsing

Comment: you can't show image by imageName only, if that image is in the bundle you can, else you need the url not the imageName

Comment: K can u please tell me how to do it ?because I dont have directly image name in url.I have it in one of the tag in XML response

Comment: but i dont have directly image name in url as I said it is like something/services/User.svc/GetXml. in this one of the tag is like <Image>46b6daca-3.png</Image>.So I retrieve it from there by doing XML parsing..?How then ?

Comment: @arizah: then you can't. You need to find the url of corresponding images. Or check with the service provider.

Answer (score 0):

if you have images in your array then use direct array value as a image like bellow..

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[[arrData valueForKey:@"Image"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 img.frame = SetFrameHere;// 
[cell.contentView addSubView:img];
```

or also add as a cell imageview like bellow..

```
cell.imageView.image = (UIImage *)[[arrData valueForKey:@"Image"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: But I m receiving error"Program received signal "SIGABRT" at this line:UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
 I m adding it in -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{} event ..Y is it so..?

Comment: what is the value of your array..?? whole array??

Comment: Name= "Orlando ";
       Image = "46b6daca-3.png";
       State = Florida;
    },
        {
        Name= "John ";
        Image = "9251bfe5-d.jpg";
        State = Florida;
    },
        {
       Name = "Michael ";
       
      
        Image = "95f27b86-8.jpg";State = Florida;
    }
) I have some more fields in each object of array

Comment: yes mate see the difference with valueForKey and use your array in which you get all data like you post above in comment ..

Comment: How should I define that imageview.I did in .h like UIImageView *imageView;and in .m I wrote as u stated eventhough I m getting error. I m adding a UItableView programatically and I guess we should define some size of the image right?If so how can I do it ?

Comment: the cell.imageView is inbuilt define in UITableViewCell .. here not required to set in .h file. and also get some idea from this link.. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: @arizah also see this http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/ i think you want something like this..

Answer (score 0):

as per you code.. try this.

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = (NSMutableDictionary *) [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[ d objectForKey:@"Image"]];
img,frame = CGRectMake("Set frame")]
[cell.contentView addSubView:img];
[img release];
```